# How to specify cookie to show on whole site until closed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, jquery-cookie

I've made a `div` that shows once per day for a user until he closes it, but the problem I have is that after going to shop and back to start site it closes automatically.

I would like some suggestions about fixing this.

I've tried using `document.cookie = 'hidecookier=1; domain=; expires=...` instead of `document.cookie ='hidecookie=1; path=/; expires=...` After putting `domain=` instead of `path=` I can't close the div anymore, it just stays there until page refresh or until going to shop and back to start site.

```js
$(function() {
  $('#header').trigger('onload');
});

function setCookieHeaderCounter() {
  if (document.cookie.indexOf('cookieheaderCounter=2') === -1) {
    if (document.cookie.indexOf('cookieheaderCounter=1') === -1) {
      document.cookie = 'cookieheaderCounter=1; path=/;';

    } else if (document.cookie.indexOf('cookieheaderCounter=1') !== -1) {
      document.cookie = 'cookieheaderCounter=2; path=/;';
    }
  }
}

function setCookieHeader() {
  var ablauf = new Date();
  var inXTagen = ablauf.getTime() + (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000); // 1 Tage
  ablauf.setTime(inXTagen);
  document.cookie = 'hidecookieheader=1; domain=; expires=' + ablauf.toGMTString();
}

if (document.cookie.indexOf('hidecookieheader=1') !== -1 || document.cookie.indexOf('cookieheaderCounter=2') !== -1) {
  jQuery('#header').hide();
} else {
  jQuery('#header').prependTo('meta_navi');
  jQuery('.header').show();
}
```

```html
<div id="header" onload="setCookieHeaderCounter()">
  <span style="font-weight: bold;"><a class="header" href=""><b></b></a></span>
  <div class="close-btn"><span id="close" class="" onclick="setCookieHeader();jQuery('#header').slideUp" style="margin-top: -8px; float: right; color: #fff; font-size: 23px;"></span></div>
</div>
```

To be clear, I want to show div `#header` on the whole site until someone closes it with span `#hinweis-close`. It can go away on refresh, that doesn't matter.

Comment: Never write your own cookie code. Find a well used one on the web such as https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie  - also please do not have inline event handlers

Comment: Also there are no onload handlers for a div

Comment: I use the same code on multiple places, such as for showing cookie agreement, figured I can use the same code with a little update to show on whole site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. use https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie by adding `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/js-cookie/2.2.0/js.cookie.min.js"></script>`
2. Use this code [DEMO](https://plungjan.name/SO/cookiejs.html)

```js
$(function() {
  var closed = Cookies.get('hinweis');
  if (!closed) {
    $('#hinweis_header').show();
  } 

  $('#hinweis-close').on('click',function() {
    Cookies.set('hinweis', 'seen');
    $('#hinweis_header').slideUp();
  });
});
```

```css
#hinweis-close {
  margin-top: -8px;
  float: right;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 23px;
}
#hinweis_header { display:none }
```

```html
<div id="hinweis_header">
  <b><a class="hinweis-header" href="<?=SHOP_URL_HTTPS?>/<?=$param["links"]["service"]?>/<?=$sprachdatei["links"]["link_hinweis"]?>">Nur heute: 10 % auf alle Jersey Stoffe >><?=$sprachdatei['header']['hinweis_header']?></a></b>

  <div class="close-btn"><span id="hinweis-close" class="rwd-buttinette-icon rwd-icon-remove-circle-1"></span></div>
</div>
```

Comment: It is not working, can't figure out why exactly since there is no error message.

Comment: Yeah, at first it didn't work because I had to add the script locally, but after that no error codes and no div showing at all.

Comment: I've actually fixed that missing quote first, since that is what I've first noticed and forgot to mention that. I'll try changing the cookie name.

Comment: I fixed it and now it shows that div on every page reload, like it doesn't save cookie or read.

Comment: Yeah, I had a typo in cookie name so it would write hinweisHeader but when it should search for cookie it couldn't find hinweisheader. Works now just how I want it, thank you very much.